# Not able to run install-tl-windows file to install texlive

Tags: installing, windows, texlive-2018

I am not able to run install-tl-windows file to install texlive. I also tried with install-tl-advanced file but it is also not showing any result. I am getting something like this attached image when I run install-tl-windows file. I don't know what is the problem and what to do now. I have texlive 2018 in my laptop and I  am using windows 8.[image].

Comment: Have you seen the related link at your right hand side? Here one: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24288/installing-texlive-windows?rq=1.